# Fiber Drink that are homogenous solutions

Tags: drinks, korean-cuisine

I have come to know **fiber** as either insoluble fiber, which doesn't disolve completely in water, and therefore doesn't make a homogenous solution, or soluble fiber, which does dissolve but also gels up.

I have known for a while a drink that considers itself to be a fiber drink; however, it's completely homogenous and liquid (not a gel). So my question is, **can this actually be a fiber drink?** from the definitions I mentioned above! I am curious because there is a [recipe that asks for this specific type of drink](http://www.healthyoligo.co.kr/recipe/recipe_Edge_step2.jsp?chasu=21), and I am wondering if I could use a different kind of fiber drink. I am wondering how this type of fiber drink is different than others.

If you are wondering what the drink is, the name is called **Miero Fiber (미에로화이바)**. It is a Korean drink.

[image: miero fiber]

Comment: Here's an [ad in English](http://www.jsglobalcambodia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/miero_brochures_for_sent_mail.pdf) (sortof), including nutritional info (sortof).

Comment: That is why I am trying to figure out if it actual does have fiber in it. I don't care about the weight-loss claim. This is Korea, and I don't know about their "FDA". Sorry they don't have V8 here.

Comment: Hello Christopher, I'm afraid that nutrition, healthiness and the physiological effects of food on your body are completely off topic on our site. So I had to remove the parts of your question which referenced this. I know that it makes potential answers much less useful to you, but we do not handle questions of how food "works" for losing weight or similar, because this is terrible flamewar fodder, and answers to such questions are rarely reliable.

Comment: @rumtscho I was not asking anything about how foods work for losing weight? What are you talking about?

Comment: @ChristopherRucinski your original question talked about fiber "working" to reduce your appetite by gelling water. I assumed that you mean that the purpose is weight loss because this is the context in which I have heard this theory, but maybe this was too quick an assumption. Anyway, whatever happens to fibre after you ate it (swelling or anything else) is off topic, so I removed that part. You can see in the edit history what is missing from the question.

Comment: No that is not what I was talking about at all. `(2)` should not have been removed at all. That is the definition of soluble fiber - not what I think. That is well known. I did not know at the time of writing that it was called that (soluble); however, I did know that was considered fiber. Both parts in the question and answer should be reinstated because they were moved based on a false assumption of weight loss

Comment: I actually found a recipe that uses Miero fiber in particular, so I was also interested in how it works, because understanding how it works can lead to understanding of where else to use it. http://www.healthyoligo.co.kr/recipe/recipe_Edge_step2.jsp?chasu=21

Comment: @ChristopherRucinski sorry, but maybe you misunderstood the rules. It is not about what is known and what isn't. If it concerns what effect the food has on you, it has to be removed. I know that it sounds harsh, but this is how we handle nutrition questions here - only a very small subset of them is tolerated at all, and your point (2) is not part of that subset. If it is not a statement which would be true of the food whether a human ate it or not, it is off topic.

Comment: I am not concerned how the food effects me. I am concerned at how it effects the food that is being made in the recipe. Is that not what this place is for?

Comment: I asked if it was fiber, because the drink seemed to go against what I knew about fiber. Then my second question was how this will effect this recipe. Is there something special about this drinks fiber vs another drinks. Because to me this type of fiber I have not seen before.

Answer (score 3):

Think soluble fiber. The following excerpt from [WebMD](http://www.webmd.com/) explains very well the difference between soluble and insoluble fiber and lists foods where each can be found.

> Soluble vs. Insoluble Fiber
>
> Soluble fiber dissolves in water. Insoluble fiber does not. [...]
>
> Soluble fibers attract water and form a gel. [...]

Comment: Just to add: According to the PFD I linked to above, the fiber in Miero is [polydextrose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polydextrose), which is synthesized from glucose and [sorbitol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorbitol). Here's another interesting little article about polydextrose, from [Slate](http://www.slate.com/articles/life/food/2009/03/dietary_fibber.html)

Comment: @Jolenealaska Very good info. And thanks for the edit.

Comment: @Jolenealaska Where is the source that Miero Fiber uses polydextrose? I also looked at the Wikipedia page you listed, and it states that polydextrose `is frequently used to increase the **non-dietary fiber** content of food`. In all the English ads I have seen for Miero Fiber, it specifically states it uses `dietary fiber`. Contrary to what you said??

Comment: @ChristopherRucinski It's in their brochure, which I linked to in the comment to the OP. 2nd ingredient "Polydextrose (dietary fiber 70%)" I don't understand the "3.551%" immediately following.

Comment: @ChristopherRucinski  Read the [Slate](http://www.slate.com/articles/life/food/2009/03/dietary_fibber.html) article. I they're saying it pretty well.

Comment: @CindyAskew we do not handle health related questions here. I understand that you answered the question as it was stated in good faith, but it did not fit our guidelines, and so neither did your answer. The measurable nutrition content of food is considered a grey area, and we allow such questions, but moderate both the questions and answers heavily to remove any references of what is supposed to happen to your body after you eat them. You cited a medical source, so I had to remove most of the text. I know most of the info disappeared, but this is really the most I can leave.

Comment: @rumtscho Thank you. I appreciate the guidance. I will learn to spot these things as I become more familiar with using the site.

Answer (score 0):

After some research into this, I think I have found an answer that is more satisfactory than the answer in comments that were made before.

### Going Over the Questions

> Can **Miero Fiber** *actually* be a **fiber drink**?

- **Yes**, it can be considered a fiber drink. It does contain **dietary fiber** called [*Polydextrose*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polydextrose). This is a soluble fiber - which is why it is a homogenous solution - all the fiber has been dissolved in the water.

### Original View

> **(1) a substance that is, at the very least, hard for the human digestive system to digest**

- This type of fiber is **Insoluble fiber**. It does not dissolve in water, and it *can be* inert metabolically - meaning it passes through your body almost un-phased. These also tend to accelerate the movement of food in the digestive system.

### 3rd View

**It does not gel because it is a *synthetic* fiber called [polydextrose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polydextrose); keyword - synthetic**. It is actually a multi-purpose ingredient synthesized from glucose which is also called dextrose. It is an ingredient that **mimics properties of fiber**, is *used to replace sugar*, and *reduces calorie and other fats*.

**Since it mimics soluble fiber, it can be called fiber, but it does not gel up because it is synthetic - not natural.**

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me that this is actually a third type of fiber. Natural soluble fiber isn't really strong gelling agent; I think it'll gel up in sufficiently high concentrations, but if you just have a bit of soluble oat fiber in water, it'll be quite liquid. So while it's possible polydextrose has different properties, I don't really see any evidence of it here. It may just not be being used in the really high concentrations it'd take to thicken the liquid. The fact that it's synthetic doesn't necessarily mean different physical properties from natural soluble fiber.

Comment: (And based on the breakdown in the PDF Jolenealaska linked to, this drink only has at most a gram of fiber per 100mL, really not that much, so I wouldn't expect it to produce a noticeable physical effect on the liquid.)